# Pagination of two or more tables with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let me just first say that I consider myself as a javascript and jQuery beginner. I am having a hard time on how to paginate couple of tables on the same page. What I am trying to achieve in particular is that I have two or more tables, but I want to paginate them with one navigation. So for instance, if I click on a "previous" link, all of the tables will switch to the previous page. I have tried to modify couple of scripts for pagination, but I cannot achieve that, since the only table that is paging is the last one. Most of them just go through the tables and set all of the rows to display: none. And then when a link is clicked, the script sets the given page to display: table-row, but it affects the page of the last table only. It seems like it keeps only the last table in memory. My opinion was to go through all of the tables everytime a pagination link is clicked, but I cannot achieve that. There is possibly a better solution, and maybe it is easy to do, but I guess I do not have the needed knowledge.

Here is some example code. This is how my HTML tables look like:

```
<div id="pagination-menu"></div>
<table>
    <tr><th>Header</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Data</td></tr>
    .
    .
    .
</table>
<table>
    <tr><th>Header</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Data</td></tr>
    .
    .
    .
</table>
```

The jQuery script is more than 100 lines, so I will just post a snippet of how the rows are displayed, creation of the links, and what happens when a link is clicked (round-x is a class that I set to all of the rows depending on the page they are on):

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.jPaginate = function(options) {

        var defaults = {
            'items_per_page' : 4,
            'active_page' : 1,
        };

        var parameters = $.extend(defaults, options);

        // Check the given values
        parameters.items_per_page = Math.max(1, parameters.items_per_page);
        parameters.active_page = Math.max(1, parameters.active_page);

        // Plugin code
        return this.each(function() {
            var $table = $(this);

            if ($table.is('table')) {
                // We get the container (table or tbody)
                var $container = $table.find('tbody');

                if ($container.length == 0) {
                    $container = $table;
                }

                var number_of_pages = 0;

                $container.find('tr').each(function(i) {
                    var $row = $(this);

                    if (i % parameters.items_per_page == 0) {
                        number_of_pages++;
                    }

                    // We add class to rows, and hide them
                    $row.addClass('round-' + number_of_pages);

                    if (number_of_pages != parameters.active_page) {
                        $row.hide();
                    }
                });

                if (number_of_pages > 1) {
                    function showPage(num) {
                        $container.find('tr').hide();
                        $container.find('.round-' + num).css('display', 'table-row');
                    }

                    var linksHTML = '';

                    for (var i = 1; i <= number_of_pages; i++) {
                        linksHTML += '<a class="round-link' + (i == parameters.active_page ? ' round-active' : '') + '" href="#">' + i + '</a> ';
                    }

                    $('#pagination-menu').html(linksHTML);

                    $('.round-link').click(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $('#pagination-menu').find('a').removeClass('round-active');
                        $(this).addClass('round-active');
                        showPage($(this).text());
                    });
                }
            } 
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

So, that's it. Maybe I need to reorganize the tables, instead of changing the jQuery code. I tried to put everything in one table, and in every row of the "big" table, I put another table?!?, but it seemed not good.

Comment: what is `$container`?

Comment: I have just updated the HTML and jQuery script.

Comment: You may want to look into using the DataTables plugin for jQuery.

Comment: I found this plugin few days ago, but I couldn't do something useful, since as I said I am a beginner and didn't understand how to actually implement the plugin, so that I can achieve what I want. Thank you for answer, anyway!

Comment: Whenever you're doing a lot of DOM manipulation like this you should set a Javascript object to the jQuery element, remove it from the DOM, do all your manipulation, then re-add it back to the DOM. For pagination you can probably just keep track of what page the table is on and have the function that builds that table accept a page (or start row) parameter. Then just call the function to rebuild the table when the user clicks on any of the page links. It's hard to explain it without a working example. Can you create a simple [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) for us?

Comment: Yes, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uk6mC/) I have created what I have at this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that for each table you overwrite `$container` each time, so it only points to the last one.

If you change `showRound` to search for all tr elements with round-* classname, you can change all of them at once.

```
function showRound(num) {
    $('tr[class^=round-]').hide();
    $('.round-' + num).css('display', 'table-row');
}
```

You can then move `$('.round-link').click(...` outside the loop since it only needs to be called once (only 1 handler per anchor instead of one handler per table per anchor)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uk6mC/2/)

If the classname `.round-` might be used elsewhere in your page, you could restrict it to your pagination menu by specifying the container in the showRound function:

```
function showRound(num) {
    $('#container').find('tr[class^=round-]').hide();
    $('#container').find('.round-' + num).css('display', 'table-row');
}
```

Comment: As I said: it keeps only the last table in memory, and I need to go through all of the tables everytime I click, but I didn't know how :) Thank you very much for your kind answer, it works perfectly!